# OnClick event of button not working always

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-framelayout, buttonclick

***fragment_maps.xml***

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MapsFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="Pickup Location">
    </Button>
</FrameLayout>
```

***MapsFragment.java***

i think due to improper implementaion of xml of  SupportMapFragment  or Framelayout ,onclick of button working sometimes and sometimes not

```
       @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container,false);
            button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.hello);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            location_permissions = new location_permissions(getContext());
            locationCallback = new LocationCallback();
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getContext());
            locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
            SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(getContext());
            mtask = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
            supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            requestpermission();

            // google maps
            supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
               // request GPS turn on if Gps is off
                    requestGPSCheck();
               // gets device current location & animate to current Latlong
                    callback();

                }
            });

            return view;
        }
```

I have set Toast message on Button OnClick event,it is not working always may be due to focus?

Comment: I recommend you to have a look on this tutorial: https://youtu.be/EZB7FTKbMlE

Comment: Need to look at the java part where you have set the onclicklistner and the part where you have written the Toast inside your onClick function. Without that we may not be able to help you.

Comment: post your activity implementation

Comment: i have edited ,please check Mapsfragment .java above,  @GauthamK thanks in advance

Comment: @srujanchandra do you really need the button is in the middle?

Comment: not necessary but  when i wrote  xml .... childs -mapview and cardview  on parent-framelayout ,UI  works but onClick are working on 3rd  or 4th click ,so i removed everything  to check first with one  button OnClick event  on middle @Rubick

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

try using

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**getContext()** uses the current view as context, so if the map isn't loaded yet it may cause the context to be not available yet.
**getApplicationContext()** instead uses the application's context which is already available by the time this fragment is loaded.

Try and let me know.